# Java JFrame, does not show contents immediately but does after minimize+restore

Tags: java, swing

```
public class GUI extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
   ...//some global variables
  public GUI ()
  {
    super("Closest Word Automaton");
    this.setSize(1000, 640);
    this.setVisible(true);
    this.setResizable(false);
    this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    this.setLayout(new CardLayout());

    initArray();

    JTabbedPane tabs = new JTabbedPane();
    tabs.add("Edit View", createEditView());
    tabs.add("Automaton View", createAutomatonView());
    tabs.add("Levenshtein Distance Calculator", createLevCalculator());
    this.add(tabs);

    addListener();

  }
```

I have a strange problem with my JFrame, when I run the program in Eclipse, the GUI shows up like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NbmSh.jpg which should not happen as it should look like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/t75Y4.jpg however the problem fixes itself after I minimize and then restore the Jframe window. Why does this happen and how can I fix it to show the GUI properly immediately upon starting up the program?

(The problem also happens on other computers)

Comment: Call `pack()` before it is set visible,  For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set your frame to visible after you add all of your components.

```
public class GUI extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
   ...//some global variables
  public GUI ()
  {
    super("Closest Word Automaton");
    this.setSize(1000, 640);
    this.setResizable(false);
    this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    this.setLayout(new CardLayout());

    initArray();

    JTabbedPane tabs = new JTabbedPane();
    tabs.add("Edit View", createEditView());
    tabs.add("Automaton View", createAutomatonView());
    tabs.add("Levenshtein Distance Calculator", createLevCalculator());
    this.add(tabs);

    this.pack();
    this.setVisible(true);  //setVisible to true after adding components

    addListener();
  }
```

Notice I called `this.pack()` as well. This will cause the JFrame to be sized properly and therefore size its child components properly as well so when you `setVisible(true)` it will appear correctly.